# Hyperledger Composer check array

Tags: javascript, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have defined an array `Account[] family` in my model.cto file and I want to access it from my logic.js. In particular I want to perform the transaction only if the receiver is in the family array of the sender.

My model.cto:

```
namespace org.digitalpayment

asset Account identified by accountId {
  o String accountId
  --> Customer owner
  o Double balance
}

participant Customer identified by customerId {
  o String customerId
  o String firstname
  o String lastname
  --> Account[] family optional
}

transaction AccountTransfer {
--> Account from
--> Account to
o Double amount
}
```

My logic.js:

```
/**
* Account transaction
* @param {org.digitalpayment.AccountTransfer} accountTransfer
* @transaction
*/
async function accountTransfer(accountTransfer) {
    if (accountTransfer.from.balance < accountTransfer.amount) {
        throw new Error("Insufficient funds");
    }

    if (/*TODO check if the family array contains the receiver account*/) {        

        // perform transaction
        accountTransfer.from.balance -= accountTransfer.amount;
        accountTransfer.to.balance += accountTransfer.amount;

        let assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.digitalpayment.Account');

        await assetRegistry.update(accountTransfer.from);
        await assetRegistry.update(accountTransfer.to);

    } else {
        throw new Error("Receiver is not part of the family");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so basically you want to first get all the accounts of a `Family` asset, and then check if the `Customer` participant is included in it? Correct me if I am wrong.
A logical set of steps would be -

1. Retrieve the `Account` based on the `to` and `from` inputs
2. Retrieve each `Customer` for each `Account` using the `owner` variable
3. Get the `family` variable from each `Customer`

```
/**
* Account transaction
* @param {org.digitalpayment.AccountTransfer} accountTransfer
* @transaction
*/
async function accountTransfer(accountTransfer) {
    if (accountTransfer.from.balance < accountTransfer.amount) {
        throw new Error("Insufficient funds");
    };

    var from = accountTransfer.from;
    var to = accountTransfer.to;
    var fromCustomer = from.owner;
    var toCustomer = to.owner;
    var fromCustomerFamily = fromCustomer.family;

    if (fromCustomerFamily && fromCustomerFamily.includes(to)) {        

        // perform transaction
        accountTransfer.from.balance -= accountTransfer.amount;
        accountTransfer.to.balance += accountTransfer.amount;

        let assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.digitalpayment.Account');

        await assetRegistry.update(accountTransfer.from);
        await assetRegistry.update(accountTransfer.to);

    } else {
        throw new Error("Receiver is not part of the family");
    }

}
```

Due to the syntax changes in the last few `Composer` versions may not work depending on the version you use in your project. If this does not work and you are using an older version, let me know and I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: This worked but substituting `fromCustomerFamily.includes(toCustomer)` with `fromCustomerFamily.includes(to)` since the array family is filled with the Account's IDs and not Customer's IDs.    Also, it's necessary to check if the array is defined (since it's optional). This can be done with `if (typeof fromCustomerFamily !== 'undefined' && fromCustomerFamily.length > 0) {}` otherwise the transaction ends with "TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined".    Thank you so much for yor help.

Comment: ah right, thought the family array was Customer. Logically that just struck me. You could simply do `if (fromCustomerFamily) `instead of using `typeof`. You do not need to check if the array is of length 0 since the `includes` function will run without it. I edited the statement as per your comment